# using twitter api from python to post messages

Tags: python, post, twitter

[diveintopython3](http://www.diveintopython3.net/http-web-services.html) tells how you can post a message to [`identi.ca`](http://identi.ca/)

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> import httplib2
>>> httplib2.debuglevel = 1
>>> h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
>>> data = {'status': 'Test update from Python 3'}
>>> h.add_credentials('diveintomark', 'MY_SECRET_PASSWORD', 'identi.ca')    
>>> resp, content = h.request('https://identi.ca/api/statuses/update.xml',
...     'POST',                                                             
...     urlencode(data),                                                    
...     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

I thought I'd do the same with twitter..

Then,I found out that they don't use basic authentication,but uses oauth.. so I thought [this library](https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library) would help

But the docs show that I need some kind of consumer_key etc for authorisation..

I have a twitter account where I login with `mygmailid@gmail.com` as username and `mypassword` as password.Is there some way I can use these for authorization?

Comment: That library is for doing oauth in GAE. You probably want [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth/1.0.1). It comes with example client code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your app to get that consumer key, and many other essentials informations.

Here you go : https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Some explanations : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#7447

As you are about to play with the API please note this link to the API console, I found it always really useful : https://dev.twitter.com/console